# Can I remove module info from Column "Extra" in Magento Admin_User Table?

Tags: magento2, database, module, magento-1, admin-user

I like my Magento database as clean as possible so whenever I uninstall an extension I also remove all data that was stored by this particular module from the database.

Now I noticed that there is some data stored in the `extra` column of the `Admin_User` Table too. It lists many old modules that I have removed in the past.

What is the purpose of this column and is it safe to remove the data that is related to exensions that are no longer installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In theory you can set a lot of things in the `extra` column in a serialized format.
But the core uses this to remember the expanded/collapsed fieldsets in the `system->configuration` sections.
So each time you expand/collapse a config fieldset a request is made to `admin/system_config/state/?container={fieldset_id}&value={1-expanded|0-collapsed}`.
the container name and value are saved in the `extra` column (see method `Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController::stateAction`) and is later retrieved in the method `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Fieldset::_getCollapseState` so you will see the fieldset just like you left it (expanded|collapsed).
I strongly advice on keeping the column.
You can remove the data from it, but this means that the next time you visit a system->cofiguration section all fieldsets will be collapsed.

Comment: Thank you @Marius for this explanation. After backing up my database I removed the entire value from the `extra` column in the `Admin_User` Table (just the value, not the column itself). This doesn't seem to cause any issues at all. After saving the config again a new value is stored into the `extra` column. All references to the old uninstalled extension are gone now.

Comment: @marius In theory you can set a lot of things in the extra column in a json format. It's actually serialized format.